# Identify an element's parent controller in Angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to identify the name of the controller in which an element resides via a directive. I initially thought this would be simple, but after a lot of searching and picking through the log output of several objects I am no closer.

As an example proof of concept id to do the following:

```
app.directive('identifyInput', function() { return {
require: 'ngModel',
link: function(scope, element, attrs, ngModelCtrl) {
  function fromUser(text) {
    var controllerName = element.CONTROLLERNAME;
    attrs.$observe('ngModel', function(modelName) {
      if (modelName) {
        alert(controllerName.' -> '.modelName);
      }
    });
  }
  ngModelCtrl.$parsers.push(fromUser);
} }; });
```

Thanks for looking!

Comment: What do you need the controller name for? Maybe there is a better solution to solve the problem without the need for a controller name. Here is a plunker with a primitive solution: http://plnkr.co/edit/CRayBsr4fPyqVYeEXrEN?p=preview

Comment: Bigger picture is I want live per-input (across several controllers) storage on the serverside. Users need to be able to leave what they have done to date in a form, then recover it via a unique identifier some time later (possibly on another machine).
My plan was to log each value in context then load them up on next visit.
I should possibly treat the form as a controller and save/load everything in that context?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you've enclosed the input within form with the name attribute specified, the form controller is published onto the current scope under this name.
It can be accessed as element.controller('form') from within the directive.